# retrieving specific value from the array of textbox with specific array button

Tags: php

I am new here and i trying to make some PHP page working but failed miserably.
I am not very good with logic nor PHP, so please bear with my stupid question and my messy codes :)

I have array of textboxes with value and there are array of buttons next to it.
what i want is each button capture specific value what i typed into the corresponding textbox

here's the piece of my code

```
<?php
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * from tempimg"); 
  while($hasil = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){   
    $i++;
  echo "<tr>
        <td align=center><input type= checkbox name=check[] value=$hasil[idFoto]</td>
        <td align=center><img src=$hasil[thumbPath]></td>
        <td align=center>$hasil[imgName]</td>
        <td align=center>$hasil[thumbPath]</td>
        <td align=center>$hasil[Path]</td>
        <td align=center>

        <input type=text align=center value=$hasil[imgLink] name=link[{$hasil['idFoto']}] id=link />

        <td align=center>
        <button type=submit onClick=\"return confirm('you clicked button  with ID: $hasil[idFoto] '+'value: '+(document.getElementById('link').value))\">
        <img src=images/sav.png alt=search-btn id=img />
        </button>
        </td>
        <td align=center><img src=images/del.png></img></td>";    
  }

      ?>
```

and here's the link of image for the PHP page I'm talking about

[image]

[image]

so I humbly request of help from people here, please help me.

EDIT: thanks to Mr. Barmar i manage to pop out the value of the text box inside the dialog box with the corresponding button,

here a new question, how to save the value from the text box that i got from clicking the corresponding button into the database?

or more simple, how to capture the value from the text box by using the button next to it and then post it on the screen using "echo"

Comment: Use javascript for this, read tutorials.

Comment: You have a key mistakes, you have placed the same ID for every element i.e. `link` this needs to be unique to each row.

Comment: Mr.Yogesh: i'm trying not use javascript

Comment: _i am not very good with logic nor PHP_. LIke a doctor who isn't very good with biology.

Comment: Mr.DevZero: can you please point out what my mistakes, i spend hours just to fix this but failed

Comment: Mr.Barmar: yes i'm not good with it, but i'm trying to learn what my mistakes, if you do know what my mistakes is, please help me out

Comment: @DevZer0 Mr.DevZer0 i got a new problem, if you're willing, please help me :)

Comment: @skycloud04 if Barmar's answer helped you should accept it

Comment: @DevZer0 Mr.DevZer0 i've fix my code using Mr.Barmar's correction, but i got a new problem, i've edited my post, please read the last sentences :)
i really appreciated your help

Comment: that's not how it works here, if you have a new problem ask a new question, and accept the answer if @Balmer helped you

Comment: @DevZer0 ah i see, i should make a new question? i thought i can continue it from the same question. Okay i got it now, i will post a new question, thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give all the id=XXX attributes unique values, by including `$i` in the ID. Then your `onclick` code can get the value of the input from the same row.

```
<?php
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * from tempimg"); 
  while($hasil = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){   
    $i++;
  echo "<tr>
        <td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='$hasil[idFoto]'</td>
        <td align='center'><img src='$hasil[thumbPath]'></td>
        <td align='center'>$hasil[imgName]</td>
        <td align='center'>$hasil[thumbPath]</td>
        <td align='center'>$hasil[Path]</td>
        <td align='center'>

        <input type='text' align='center' value='$hasil[imgLink]' name='link[{$hasil['idFoto']}]' id='link$i' />

        <td align='center'>
        <button type='submit' onclick='return confirm(\"you clicked button  with ID: $hasil[idFoto] \"+\"value: \"+(document.getElementById(\"link$i\").value))'>
        <img src='images/sav.png' alt='search-btn' id='img$i' />
        </button>
        </td>
        <td align='center'><img src='images/del.png' /></td>";    
  }

      ?>
```

You should also put quotes around all attribute values.

Comment: urm, sorry Mr.Barmar for being rude. But after i retype my codes as you said, the dialog box won't appear anymore. Then i reverted back my code, the dialog box works, and i try to add $i for attribute unique values, but again the dialog box stopped working

EDIT: thank you very much Mr.Barmar, now it works :)
i appreciate your scolding and your help :D

Comment: Mr.Barmar sorry to disturb you again. At the code above, we only get the value in the dialog box, if i want to save it to database, no atleast if i want to display it on screen using "echo" what should i do?